# how to load workbench ui in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm developing a vscode extension, and I'm currently facing a problem, and I'd like to seek your help.

I want to use the VScode UI in the webview created by the plug-in to ensure the consistency of the user's vision. How do I refer to the resource?

I tried the following:

1. Use appRoot to directly splice `vscode-file://vscode-app/`, displaying network errors
2. Use appRoot to refer to 'file://' and find: Not allowed to load local resource
3. Use asWebviewUri, display HTTP code 401

```js
const cssfile = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(vscode.env.appRoot,"out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.css"));
const cssurl = this.view.webview.asWebviewUri(cssfile);
console.log(cssurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason through the official documentation, because of security restrictions, you need to add approot to the settings.

Use the WebviewOptions.localResourceRoots to allow access to additional local resources.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#loading-local-content